# how to center a flexibox in browser window?

Tags: css

I'd like to center a flexibox in browser window, the code in following jsfiddle works without centering, when the browser screen changes, the image and text change in a responsive way,

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srad0fmy/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">   <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
     #container {
     display: flex;
     /*width: 1400px;*/
     margin: auto;
     }
     #container .video {
     border: 5px solid red;
     width: 750px;
     max-width: 100%;
     }
     #container .desc {
     background-color: blue;
     max-width: 100%;
     }
  </style>   </head>   <body>
  <div id="container">
     <div class="video">
        <img src="https://futuranexa.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/funny_cow_egg-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg"
           style="max-width: 100%">
     </div>
     <div class="learn">
        <p>
           isque perfecto dissentiet cum et, sit ut quot mandamus, ut vim    tibique splendide instructior.
        <p>
     </div>
  </div>   </body></html>
```

if I uncomment the  /*width: 1400px;*/ line, the flexibox is centered, but the image and text will not change responsively when browser screen changes, any hint? Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i understand what you're asking for after a few reads so here's what I have done on your coding:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
}

#container .video {
    border: 5px solid red;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#container .desc {
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="video">
        <img src="https://futuranexa.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/funny_cow_egg-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg"
             style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="learn">
        <p>
            isque perfecto dissentiet cum et, sit ut quot mandamus, ut vim    tibique splendide instructior.
        <p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generally to make the text center beneath the image dependant on the size you need to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` Also you should always use `flex-basis: xyz%;` instead of `width: xyz%` give this a try and let me know if it is what you were after.

Comment: one more thing, the text under class='learn', it goes under the image immediately, is there a way to just wordwrap the contents until a min width before it goes beath the image?

Comment: It should only move under the image once the space of your monitor is too small. I am on a 21" and it shows side by side until i reduce the browser width.

Comment: flex-wrap will move the text on the right under image once the window is smaller, since justify-content is center, so the text is in the center, is there a way to have it on the left? this will look nicer